# Network between host and guest operating system (VMware virtual machines)

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, networking, virtual-machine, vmware

On my computer (OS: Windows 7) I have installed VMware and created one virtual machine(OS: Windows XP), can I create a network between my host OS (windows 7) and guest OS (windows XP) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMware already creates a network between your actual machines and the virtual machines. The virtual machines each, by default, can get their own IP address to access network resource and the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to configure each VM to use a Network Adaptor and then within the VM set the network settings you need.

Withing Microsoft Virtual PC you have to set the network adaptor with the VM closed, imagine it's the same in VMWare.